# Can I track how many trees I have planted?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I know if I plant 100+ trees on Arrrbor Day, I get better rewards the next Arrrbor Day for whatever tree type I planted.

Is there any way to track this, short of just keeping a count in my head?

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically, though it's one adventure per tree so you can watch you adventure count or use the `/timer` command.